# How to construct Control-Z with square root of swap?

Tags: quantum-algorithms, circuit-construction

How to construct Control-Z with square root of swap(up to some single qubit operations)? In some papers it just directly mention that it's possible but didn't tell how to do.

Answer (score 3):

Found by just trying stuff in Quirk:

[image: cz from sqrt swap]

Answer (score 0):

To add to the circuit by @Craig, the reason why papers tend to mention that some gate is obtainable by $\sqrt{swap}$ upto a few single qubit gates is because the set that contains the $\sqrt{swap}$ gate and all the one qubit gates is considered to be a universal set of quantum gates. That is, by just using just the $\sqrt{swap}$ gate and some single qubit gates, it is possible to construct any single or multi qubit quantum gate.